# Indispensable emacs modes for rails?

Tags: ruby-mode

Are there definitive must-have modes when developing on rails, I usually get absorbed on the sea of different packages out there, is there some place that list them?

Comment: This question is too broad to be answerable.

Comment: I suspect you got a downvote because the question, as it is currently written, is not very well-suited to the site.  It's very broad right now, and would invite a lot of opinion-based, "my favorite package is *x*" answers.  Please start by looking at the relevant [EmacsWiki node](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RubyOnRails), and then consider editing your question to make it more specific and answerable.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely check both [rspec-mode](https://github.com/pezra/rspec-mode) and [robe](https://github.com/dgutov/robe)

Answer (score 1):

[projectile-rails](https://github.com/asok/projectile-rails) is a nice all-around mode, especially for navigating between files within a project.